# groovy executing shell commands on remote server

Tags: groovy, ssh

I have an issue about executing shell commands on a remote server.

I'm trying various solutions and I have one working but it is not optimized in terms of maintenance : I use a batch file that launches putty which connects to the remote server ans sends the command.

ie. in groovy :

```
def batchFile = "C:\\Validation\\Tests_Auto\\Scripts\\remote_process\\setOldDate.bat"
Runtime.runtime.exec(batchFile)
```

and in my batch file :

```
c:
cd C:\Validation\Tests_Auto\Scripts\remote_process\
putty.exe -ssh root@xx.xx.xx.xx -pw **** -m "C:\Validation\Tests_Auto\Scripts\remote_process\setOldDate.txt"
```

setOldDate.txt contains the command `date -s @1522018800`

This works. However I'd like to launch it in a cleaner way, either avoiding the use of text file for the command or, better, avoiding using putty.
I tried several another way to do the same thing but it doesn't work. I think I'm not too far but I need a little help.

I tried to launch a direct command via ssh:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec('"c:\\Program Files\\OpenSSH\\bin\\ssh.exe" root:****@xx.xx.xx.xx date -s @1522018800')
```

I'd be grateful if anyone could help

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, compiling my various research and struggling to fit my environment constraints (groovy in soapui), I ended up with the following solution that works for me :

download jsch-0.1.54.jar and set it in C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-2.3.0\bin\ext

use the following groovy script :

```
import java.util.Properties
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session


def ip = context.expand( '${#Project#projectEndpoint}' )


    try
    {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
          Session session = jsch.getSession("root","$ip", 22);
          session.setPassword("****");

          // Avoid asking for key confirmation
          Properties prop = new Properties();
          prop.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
          session.setConfig(prop);

          session.connect();


        // SSH Channel
        ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");

            // Execute command
            //channelssh.setCommand("date -s @1520018000"); // change date
            channelssh.setCommand("ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org"); // restore date
            channelssh.connect();
            channelssh.disconnect();



    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.info "exception : " + e
      System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
            session.disconnect();
    }
```

**UPGRADE**

Here is a generalization I've made as my needs evolved. The following script, still using jsch allows to send any command.
This deals with host checking and eliminates hazards due to no host checking.
User and password are passed as parameters

```
import java.util.Properties
import com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelExec
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session

import java.util.regex.Pattern

def ip = context.expand( '${get endpoint#endpoint}' )
ip = ip.replaceFirst("http[s]?://","")

def user = context.expand( '${#Project#ssh_user}' )
def password = context.expand( '${#Project#ssh_password}' )

def command = context.expand( '${#TestCase#command}' )

def timeout = context.expand( '${#TestCase#timeout_ms}' )
if (timeout == "")
    timeout = 1000 // default timeout 1s
else
    timeout = timeout.toInteger()

log.info "command = " + command

Session session
try
{
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    session = jsch.getSession(user,ip, 22);
    session.setPassword(password);
    //log.info "user : $user"
    //log.info "set password : $password"

    //log.info System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.ssh/known_hosts"
    jsch.setKnownHosts(System.getProperty("user.home")+"/.ssh/known_hosts");

    session.connect();
    //log.info "session connect"


    // SSH Channel
    ChannelExec channelssh = (ChannelExec)session.openChannel("exec");

    // Execute command
    channelssh.setCommand(command);
    InputStream commandOutput = channelssh.getInputStream();

    channelssh.connect();

    int readByte = commandOutput.read();

    outputBuffer = [];

    // timeout to avoid infinite loop
    while((readByte != -1) && (timeout > 0))
    {
        outputBuffer.add(readByte)
        readByte = commandOutput.read();
        timeout = timeout -1
    }

    // process output
    outputBuffer = outputBuffer as byte[]

    // convert byte array into string
    output = new String(outputBuffer, "UTF-8")

    sleep(3000)
    //log.info "disconnect"
    channelssh.disconnect();

    testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("cmd_output", output)
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    msg = "exception : " + e
    log.error msg
    testRunner.fail(msg)
}
finally
{
    session.disconnect();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
@Grab(group='com.jcraft', module='jsch', version='0.1.54')

def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.sshexec( host:"somehost", username:"dude", password:"yo", command:"touch somefile" )
```

for other `sshexec` and `scp` tasks parameters see doc:

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/scp.html

**for soapui**

this method using `apache ant` + `jsch-0.1.54.jar`

the only way i know for soapui:

download the following libraries and put them into `soapui\bin\endorsed` directory (create the `endorsed` directory)

- https://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant/1.9.11/ant-1.9.11.jar
- https://central.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ant/ant-launcher/1.9.11/ant-launcher-1.9.11.jar
- https://central.maven.org/maven2/com/jcraft/jsch/0.1.54/jsch-0.1.54.jar

edit the `soapui\bin\soapui.bat` and add the following line where other `JAVA_OPTS` are defined:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%SOAPUI_HOME%endorsed"
```

that's because `ant` libs must be loaded before groovy.

then the code above should work in soapui (except `@Grab`)

**Alternatively** you can download only `jsch-XXX.jar` into existing `soapui\bin\ext` directory  and use `jsch` library directly from groovy

see examples: http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/

or search for [groovy jsch](https://www.google.com/search?q=groovy+jsch) examples

Comment: thank you very much ! I'm not much familiar with java, do you have any idea of where I can set the .jar file ? actually I'm using soapui

Comment: modified the answer

Comment: Won't you better grab `ant-jsch` (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ant/ant-jsch)?