# How to read and check content of file on external server with JMeter?

Tags: groovy, ssh, jmeter, beanshell

I'm sorry if this is a very basic question, but I'm new to JMeter and don't have much experience with basics on working across multiple servers.

What I would like to do is the following:
Let's say my JMeter linux server is 1.2.3.44 and the files I want to read are on server 1.2.3.55. Also, I have a server 1.2.3.66, which is a windows server which also has JMeter on it and preferably I would like to run scripts from this one if possible (because I could avoid SCP-ing my script to the other server without GUI after each adjustment).

So my system places messages in a directory on 1.2.3.55. I have the following variables;

> dirpath: /tmp/dir/dir/
>
> filepath: ${filename}.txt
>
> completepath: ${dirpath}${filepath}
>
> otherserver: 1.2.3.55

I would like to use JMeter to look into that file and read the first (and only) line and compare it to what I'm expecting. What I have so far is a BeanShell Sampler that I am able to get to read a file on the same server that I run the JMeter script on (.66) by doing this:

```
BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(vars.get("completepath")));

int counter = 1;
content = fileReader.readLine();
while ((nextLine = fileReader.readLine()) != null)
{
    content = content + "\n" + nextLine;
    counter++;
}
vars.put("content", content);

x = vars.get("content");
```

However, I cannot figure out how to access a file on another server (the .55), and what the filepath should be in that case...

I have  used the OS Process Sampler before in a different testcase to access a linux server on which I had a bash script to ssh to another server and run a different bash script there that would place some files in a directory. However, I have no idea how to do that and also actually read the contents of that file. Should I look at bash scripting again (I really don't know much about it)? Or is there a way to do that in JMeter that is easier?

Can I do something like for the variable completepath: 1.2.3.55/tmp/dir/dir/filename.txt ?

Comment: similar because scp & sshexec using same library, but for soapui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49922897/groovy-executing-shell-commands-on-remote-server/49925447?r=SearchResults#49925447

Comment: I don't really understand that post, what is soapui and how is it connected to JMeter?

Comment: It is connected through groovy. Soapui is just another java application as jmeter. You can use the same library in jmeter to access remote files from groovy.